# Scheduled messages with RabbitMQ

Tags: rabbitmq, message-queue, microservices

I'm looking for a solution to have scheduled messages with RabbitMQ, so not only delaying the messages as described in several sources but schedule it to have a message e.g. every day.

If not RabbitMQ, any other solutions out there you can think of and you'd suggest for a microservices environment using a message-bus?
So it's really about combining the concept of a task-scheduler and a message bus ...

Or is it better to use a job scheduler just to push messages to the message queue, e.g. using rundeck in combination with RabbitMQ?

Comment: How about a simple cron ? Maybe you could have a microservices that is used as a message scheduler, and would simply interact with cron?

Comment: Did you look at using NServiceBus?

Comment: BTW, I ended up using a combination of a cron based scheduler and also having https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-delayed-message-exchange in place ...

Comment: I found this [link](https://medium.com/@twobuckchuck/rabbitmq-scheduling-messages-with-sneakers-18089e8aa7d2) interesting. The solution is to create a delayed exchange in RabbitMQ and after the delay the message is send to the queue. It's not native in RabbitMQ though but it's a plugin.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

> Or is it better to use a job scheduler just to push messages to the message queue, e.g. using rundeck in combination with RabbitMQ?

yes.

RabbitMQ is not designed to handle scheduling, and attempting to use it for that will just be painful (at best).

It is best to use another scheduling system, like cron jobs or rundeck or any of the other numerous scheduling tools available. From that tool, you can execute code that will push messages across RabbitMQ, triggering work in other parts of your system.

Comment: Thx, I went with this approach so far; it's a bit more setup work, but so far I am pretty happy about having a scheduler and RabbitMQ separated in two different services. Seems definitely to pay off.

Answer (score -1):

You may try ActiveMQ, It supports crontab schedule, and it provides a web console to setup the schedule too. If you want to schedule from code, it may looks like:

```
MessageProducer producer = session.createProducer(destination);
TextMessage message = session.createTextMessage("test msg");
message.setStringProperty(ScheduledMessage.AMQ_SCHEDULED_CRON, "0 * * * *");
producer.send(message);
```